# Understaning the Vapply function in R

Tags: r

I am not familiar with the following error code and was wondering if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

```
str(pw1a)
'data.frame':   1412 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ EtOH_2: num  1 6 1 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 ...
 $ HSCRP : Factor w/ 2 levels "High Risk","Low or Moderate Risk": 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 - attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' Named int [1:2376] 3 6 7 11 13 14 16 18 20 21 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2376] "3" "6" "7" "11" ...
> # non-parametric
> pairwise_comparisons(
+   data = pw1a,
+   x = EtOH_2,
+   y = HSCRP,
+   type = "nonparametric",
+   paired = TRUE,
+   p.adjust.method = "BY"
+ )
Error in vapply(seq_along(ivec), function(k) { : values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 14
```

Reference:
https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/pairwiseComparisons/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will provide an example of usage of `vapply` to present the source of the problem. The 3th argument of `vapply` is `FUN.VALUE` which specifying a type and length of return element for each iteration. `vapply` secures us against wrong number of returned elements and incorrect types. This should clarify the background.

```r
vapply(1:10, function(x) x, numeric(1))
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
vapply(1:10, function(x) x, numeric(2))
#> Error in vapply(1:10, function(x) x, numeric(2)): values must be length 2,
#>  but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 1
vapply(1:10, function(x) x, character(1))
#> Error in vapply(1:10, function(x) x, character(1)): values must be type 'character',
#>  but FUN(X[[1]]) result is type 'integer'
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>